# If two matrices are similar are their submatrices again similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am struggling a bit with the following: if we have two similar matrices and we delete one column and one row in both of them are they again similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to think about $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} b & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$.